# Criar um Jogo em linguagem c com o MCU 8051 IDE

Tags: c, microcontrolador-8051

Estou a tentar desenvolver um jogo no âmbito da unidade curricular de microprocessadores, sendo assim, o jogo consiste num boneco que tem de se desviar de bombas, portanto tenho de criar o boneco, as bombas e pô-los a mexer. Já tenho uma boa parte de código mas acho que ele fica preso num ciclo while e não percebo o porque. Será que expondo aqui um pedaço do meu código são capazes de me ajudar??

```
void main (void)
{   
unsigned char i,counter=1;

start=0;
end=0;
IE=0b10000101;
En=1;
LCD_init ();
while(start!=0);
while(end==1);
Inicio();
CriarBonecoBomba();
x=0;
y=0;
score=0;

for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    var[0][i]=' ';
    var[1][i]=' ';
}
while(end==0) // salta da 1a interrupção la ao fundo para aqui e não sai daqui
{
    while (start==1)
    {
        MovBoneco();
        desloca_esq();
        if((counter+3)%6==0)
            cria_bomba(1);
        else
            if(counter%6==0)
                cria_bomba(2);
            else
                cria_bomba(0);
        if(var[y][x]==1|| 1==var[y][x-1])
        {
            LCD_comando(0b10000000);
            LCD_date(' ');
            LCD_date(' ');
            LCD_date(' ');
            LCD_date('G');
            LCD_date('A');  
            LCD_date('M');
            LCD_date('E');
            LCD_date(' ');
            LCD_date('O');
            LCD_date('V');
            LCD_date('E');
            LCD_date('R');
            while(1);
        }
    MovBoneco();
    AtualizarLCD();
    counter++;
    if(var[0][0]==1||var[1][0]==1)
        score=score+5;
    display7segmentos();
}
}
}

void RSIEXT0(void)__interrupt (0)
{
start=1;
}

void RSIEXT1(void)__interrupt (2)
{
end==1;
}
```

Comment: Qual o compilador que você está utilizando? Aonde você detecta a colisão com a bomba? Você está resetando o valor da variável *start* quando a bomba atinge o boneco?

Comment: Falta os includes no seu código para que seja possivel ao menos tentar compilar o seu script

Comment: Não me parece que essa pergunta deveria ser suspensa como não clara. A seguinte frase diz tudo: "Já tenho uma boa parte de código mas acho que ele fica preso num ciclo while e não percebo o porque".

Comment: Eu tenho os includes no meu codigo, e ele compila corretamente, o problema é que já fiz tudo e mais alguma coisa e nao consigo que ele inicie sequer.  o complilaqdor que estou a usar é o MCU 8051 IDE.

Comment: Em qual dos `while`'s ele fica preso?

Comment: Logo no primeiro while, while(start!=0).

Answer (score 2):

Tanto `start` como `end` são inicializadas com o valor zero (0) logo ao início da sua função `main`. Elas não foram declaradas com um tipo (o compilador que você usa não gera nenhum aviso disso?) ou então você as declarou fora do escopo da função e não colocou esse código na pergunta.

Se for o caso 1, mesmo o compilador (possivelmente) não reclamando o escopo das variáveis é local (isto é, pertence somente à função `main`). E ai, qualquer alteração externa na verdade muda variáveis diferentes (de outro escopo).

Se for o caso 2 (que eu acho mais provável), as variáveis são globais e tudo deveria funcionar corretamente (supondo-se que as suas "interrupções" estejam sendo chamadas de fato). De todas as formas, há um errinho pequeno na função `RSIEXT1` onde você usa o operador de igualdade (dois sinais de igual: `==`) ao invés do operador de atribuição (um só sinal de igual: `=`). :)